# Read specific pixel region from large Tiff file in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, tiff, large-files

I was wondering if anyone have specific advice for reading a defined pixel region of a large Tiff image. My images are well over 8 GB and I have defined pixel region coordinates that I would like to read and process independent of the whole image.

I have started to look at python GDAL,but I have been having trouble installing it into my Anaconda 3 environment so I am looking for all other alternatives.

Any example code describing how to read a region from rows = 0 : 500 and colmuns = 0:500 would also be GREATLY appreciated, with all 3 RGB levels would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `pyvips` - I am sure John, the author, will answer.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response :). I actually did look into pyvips, but I couldn't figure out how to properly install it also into my anaconda environment.

Comment: It is a tiled TIFF, I presume?

Comment: Hello Mark :) Yes, pyvips can do what you want, assuming (as Chris says) these are tiled TIFFs. There's no anaconda package, unfortunately, you'd need to switch to standard Python.